# Django - Using same model twice in a fieldset

Tags: django, django-models

I'm would like to use the Party model twice (but with different values) in a fieldset in the Admin panel but can't figure out how to do it. Is there a way? Any help is appreciated!

```
from django.contrib import admin
from mvp.models import Contract, Party
# Register your models here.

class ContractAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):

    fieldsets = [
        (None,               {'fields': ('contract_number', 'contract_type', 'contract_startdate', 'contract_enddate','contract_renewaldate', 'contract_value', 'contract_currency', 'party')}),
    ]

    search_fields = ['contract_number', 'party__party_name']
    list_display = ('contract_number', 'contract_type', 'contract_startdate', 'contract_enddate', 'contract_renewaldate')


admin.site.register(Contract, ContractAdmin)
admin.site.register(Party)
```

And here is models.py

```
class Party(models.Model):
    party_name = models.CharField('Name', max_length=60)
    party_street = models.CharField('Street', max_length=60)
    party_city = models.CharField('City', max_length=60)
    party_zip = models.CharField('Zip/Postal Code', max_length=60)
    party_country = models.CharField('Country', max_length=60)
    party_email = models.CharField('Email', max_length=60)
    party_fax = models.CharField('Fax', max_length=60)
    party_phone = models.CharField('Phone', max_length=60)
    def __unicode__(self):
        return self.party_name
    pass

class Contract(models.Model):
    CONTRACT_TYPES = (
        ('PNS', 'Purchase and Sale'),
        ('CDA', 'Confidential Disclosure Agreement'),
        ('DIS', 'Distribution'),
        ('LIC', 'Licensing Agreement'),
        ('SOW', 'Statement of Work'),
        ('IMP', 'Implementation Agreement'),
        )
    CURRENCY_TYPES = (
        ('CAD', 'CAD'),
        ('EUR', 'EUR'),
        ('USD', 'USD'),
        )
    party = models.ForeignKey(Party)
    contract_number = models.CharField('Contract Number', db_index=True,     max_length=60, primary_key=True)
    contract_type = models.CharField('Contract Type', db_index=True, max_length=3, choices=CONTRACT_TYPES)
    contract_startdate = models.DateField('Start Date')
    contract_enddate = models.DateField('End Date')
    contract_renewaldate = models.DateField('Renewal Date')
    contract_value = models.IntegerField('Value')
    contract_currency= models.CharField('Currency', db_index=True, max_length=3, choices=CURRENCY_TYPES)
    def __unicode__(self):
        return self.contract_type
```

Comment: The question is not clear. Can you post your models.py?

Comment: Selcuk I edited my question and added models.py

Comment: What do you expect to see in admin? You have one foreign key to Party from Contract. How can you use it twice?

Comment: Sorry if I'm not making myself clear.

I would like to be able to input two different party values in the ContractAdmin fieldset. is there anyway of doing that without using a separate class Party(models.Model)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You currently have a `ForeignKey` relation from `Contract` to `Party`, which means that you can only choose one `Party` per `Contract`. This is called a 'one-to-many relationship'. What you should do is to change it to a 'many-to-many' relation.

Change the line:

```
party = models.ForeignKey(Party)
```

to

```
party = models.ManyToManyField(Party)
```

Then you can use filter_vertical or filter_horizontal in your ModelAdmin to add/remove Parties:

```
class ContractAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    ....
    filter_horizontal = ('party',)
```

**Update**: If you will only need 2 parties to be associated with a contract, you can simply add a second field by adding

```
party2 = models.ForeignKey(Party, related_name='contract2')
```

but in this case you won't have access to Django ORM's goodies like getting all the contracts related to a party by simply writing `party.contracts`. If you will never need the reverse traversal; you can use `related_name='+'` to disable it altogether.

Comment: I'd rather not use a many-to-many as it should be a one-to-many relationship.

How about doing this in models.py
    party1 = models.ForeignKey(Party, related_name="Party1")

Comment: Do you only need 2 parties to be associated? Will you never need more than 2?

Comment: At this time no, but maybe later.

Comment: thanks. I'll keep the many-to-many solve in mind for later. 

Thanks for the help guys!

Answer (score -1):

Create an innline model for party

```
from django.contrib import admin

    class PartyAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
         list_display = ('party_name',)

    class PartyInline(admin.TabularInline):
        model = Party

    class ContracAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    fieldsets = [
            (None,               {'fields': ('contract_number', 'contract_type', 'contract_startdate', 'contract_enddate','contract_renewaldate', 'contract_value', 'contract_currency')}),
        ]

        search_fields = ['contract_number', 'party__party_name']
        list_display = ('contract_number', 'contract_type', 'contract_startdate', 'contract_enddate', 'contract_renewaldate')
        inlines = [
            PartyInline,
        ]


admin.site.register(Contract, ContractAdmin)
admin.site.register(Party, PartyAdmin)
```

Comment: @Gunpowderboy I don't see how could this possibly work. Are you sure it works?

Comment: @Selcuk You are right it didn't behave the way I wanted.

Comment: @Gunpowderboy Yasel, your answer requires adding a foreign key to Contract in Party model and even then it will only allow a single contract to be associated with each party. Try the method I suggested in my answer.

Comment: @Selcuk, I assumed that what Gunpowderboy needed, was to edit the Party model in two different ways in the admin, the model separately and as part of the model Contract.
The idea was not to create two separate models, was a matter of the administration interface.